# IDE Netbeans 8.1 - проблема с подключением к Java DB

Tags: php, mysql

Подскажите пожалуйста как решить проблему :

Писал запрос к базе в php `mysql_query(...)`, увидел во всплывающей подсказке вариант "подключить базу данных" (или что-то в этом роде). Из любопытства решил воспользоваться - оно начало подключаться, причём явно не к MySQL серверу, я отменил подключение, но оно не успокоилось - теперь каждый раз когда я что-то меняю в строке запроса оно запускает подключение, прерывая мне работу и создавая неудобства.

Как это подключение успокоить раз и навсегда?

Comment: Постарайтесь писать более развернутые вопросы. Поясните, в чем именно вы видите проблему, как её воспроизвести, что вы хотите получить в результате и т. д.